# Values of k possible in leal

Tags: assembly, x86

Let's say `%edi` would be x and k is a constant integer (positive). If I wanna do `%eax<-k*x` so that it's faster than `imul`, I use leal, right? So my question is, if the scaling factor is 1, 2, 4, 8, and I use a single `leal` instruction, what values of k are possible? I'm thinking it would be 2^k, but I'm not sure about it, could someone explain it to me?

And if I use a pair of leal instructions one after the other, what values of k are possible?

Comment: You can only multiply a register by the constants you've noted and then add the result to another register in single LEA instruction so that makes the values of k easy to enumerate in the single instruction case. The only tricky part is knowing that the other register can be the same register.

Answer (score 1):

Lea can shift a register by 0,1,2 or 3 bits and also add the same register again.

This means lea can do the following multiplications:

```
                                                              latency
   LEA                       ALTERNATIVE (only if faster)     LEA  ALT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------   
1: lea eax,[eax]             nop                               1    0
2: lea eax,[eax+eax]         add eax,eax                       1    1
3: lea eax,[eax*2+eax]       -                                 2    -
4: lea eax,[eax*4]           shl eax,2                         2    1
5: lea eax,[eax*4+eax]       -                                 2    -
6: -                         imul eax,6                        -    3
7: -                         imul eax,7                        -    3
8: lea eax,[eax*8]           shl eax,3                         2    1
9: lea eax,[eax*8+eax]       -                                 2    -
```

Note that the magic of `lea` does not come free.
On all but the most modern processors a 'complex' lea will take an extra CPU cycle to resolve.
A complex lea is one with a scaling factor or with 3 operands.
If you feel like resorting to 2 lea's e.g. to multiply by 10, an imul will often be faster.

The great thing about `lea` is that it does not modify the flags register, unlike most alternatives.

> And if I use a pair of lea instructions one after the other....

Note that (i)mul only takes 3 cycles minimum to resolve. A complex lea will take 2 cycles. So you cannot beat (i)mul by combining 2 lea's.
Plain powers of 2 are best done using a simple `shl`

I leave the translation to PDP11 syntax as an exercise for the reader.
Latencies are typical Intel Core2 timings, this applies to many modern registers.
Skylake and newer are faster.

Comment: The ADD and SHL alternatives are destructive, but IMUL-immediate is actually a 3-operand instruction:  `imul dest, src, imm32` (since it has a whole opcode to itself, unlike most immediate instructions that steal the /r field of the ModRM byte as extra opcode bits).

Comment: If you're really listing Core2 timings, then LEA is always 1 cycle latency even for complex addressing modes, according to Agner Fog's table (for Merom/Conroe and Wolfdale/Penryn, and also Nehalem).  SnB was the first microarch to make complex or RIP-relative LEA slower (3 cycles), and it's still 1 or 3 cycles on Skylake.  SnB standardized uop latencies (to reduce conflicts from multiple uops producing a result in the same cycle), so there are no 2-cycle latency uops.  This makes it easier for the out-of-order scheduler to decide which uops to send to execution ports each cycle.

Comment: Also, according to Agner Fog's table, LEA is only slow when it has 3 components.  (base + index + displacement).  All of your example have no displacement, so they should all be 1 cycle LEAs.